# docker compose how to run multi images with no service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker and still testing different features of docker.

Currently, I am learning `docker-compose` with the pure OS loaded (alpine and ubuntu)

my `docker-compose` yaml file :

```
    version: '3.7'
    services:
      alpine1:
        image: alpine:latest
      ubuntu2:
        image: ubuntu:latest
```

Output of docker ps -a

```
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
    2004175db96b        ubuntu:latest       "/bin/bash"         25 minutes ago      Exited (0) 3 seconds ago                        dockerize_ubuntu2_1
    eaae1f731b71        alpine:latest       "/bin/sh"           25 minutes ago      Exited (0) 25 minutes ago                       dockerize_alpine1_1
```

These images are still pure image, I can not start both the container,

with docker I usually use :

`docker run -t alpine`

then I can start the container.

Please help me with my problem above.

I still want to run the container from pure images.

Comment: Neither unmodified base-OS images nor containers that just sit idle are really useful.  I'd recommend reading Docker's [Get Started, Part 2: Containers](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) tutorial, which walks through the process of building and running a custom image.  In standard usage an image contains one packaged application (the `ubuntu` image contains none) and the corresponding container runs that application (not a shell and not an artificial task to keep an empty container alive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add commands to prevent the containers to be exited:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  alpine1:
    image: alpine:latest
    command: tail -f /dev/null
  ubuntu2:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```

start them:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: would you please explained it to me, is the output is same with docker command docker run -it ubuntu:latest, is it prevent exit also?

Comment: -it start the container with interactive shell so you are on the container terminal .you can use `tty` also in compose to produce the same behavior